# Is possible to animate using Transition between :after and :focus?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations

```
.input-container {
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    border: solid 2px $light;
    border-radius: 2em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5625em;


    &:after{
        content: '';
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        box-shadow: 0 0 20px white;
        border-radius: 2em;
        pointer-events: none;
        opacity: 0; //animate this
        transition: opacity 1s; // using this
    }

    &:focus{
        opacity: 1; //to this
    }
}
```

Usually transition is used to animate between the selector and its pseudoclass. I'm trying to animate the box-shadow property using opacity as it would kill performance if I would animate it directly using Transition, so I need to animate from one pseudoclass to another. Is it possible to achieve this using only CSS?

Answer (score 1):

The way you asked it in the question title does not really make sense - `:after` is not a *state* an element can be in like `:focus`, so there is no "switching between them" either.

(`::before`/`::after` are commonly referred to as pseudo *elements*, not classes. To make the distinction between them and the actual pseudo classes more obvious, the syntax has been updated, so that these to now use a double colon - optional, you can still use the "old", single colon syntax as well.)

What you actually want, is give the pseudo element created by `:after` a different opacity, when the actual element is in the `:focus` state - so you just need to *do that*: Put `&:focus` *inside* `&:after{ ...}`, so that the final selector will become `.input-container:after:focus`

Don't worry about the order - `.input-container:focus:after` might seem more logical, after all the "real" element is in focus state, not the pseudo element - but the order does not matter here, both achieve the same.

Comment: oh, right. ::after and ::before are pseudo elements, my bad. Fine. But how will I animate an input:after:focus? is it even possible?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. _What_ do you want to "animate" (actually, transition), and on what "event"? I assumed you wanted to change the opacity of the pseudo element when the real element has focus? Then `input:after:focus` is the right selector to specify that opacity. And the transition you add for the "normal" state of the pseudo element (or only this selector, if you want the transition to occur only in the one direction, or for both if you want to specify different transition parameters.)